# GPU usage monitoring (CUDA)

Tags: monitoring, gpu

I installed CUDA toolkit on my computer and started BOINC project on GPU. In BOINC I can see that it is running on GPU, but is there a tool that can show me more details about that what is running on GPU - GPU usage and memory usage?

Answer (score 489, accepted):

For Nvidia GPUs there is a tool `nvidia-smi` that can show memory usage, GPU utilization and temperature of GPU. There also is a list of compute processes and few more options but my graphic card (GeForce 9600 GT) is not fully supported.

```
Sun May 13 20:02:49 2012       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.40   Driver Version: 295.40         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  GeForce 9600 GT           | 0000:01:00.0  N/A    |       N/A        N/A |
|   0%   51 C  N/A   N/A /  N/A |  90%  459MB /  511MB |  N/A      Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.           Not Supported                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: My ION chip does not show usage, either. :/

Comment: For Linux and for some versions of Windows, but **not for Unix** – `nvidia-smi` ships [with NVIDIA GPU display drivers on Linux, and with 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html).

Comment: `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi`, will keep the output updated without filling your terminal with output.

Comment: @Bar Good tip. `watch -d -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` will be even better.

Comment: @zeekvfu I think it'd be better to explain what does the `-d` flag do

Comment: @donlucacorleone `man watch` tells us the `-d` flag highlights differences between the outputs, so it can aid in highlighting which metrics are changing over time.

Comment: If the above format is too black box (un-configurable) for you or you find the screen too busy, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda/489559#489559.

Comment: instead of `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` you can also use `nvidia-smi --loop-ms=500`

Answer (score 156):

For linux, use `nvidia-smi -l 1` will continually give you the gpu usage info, with in refresh interval of 1 second.

Comment: I prefer to use `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` to obtain continuous updates without filling the terminal with output

Comment: Using watch means your starting a new process every second to poll the cards. Better to do -l, and not every second, I'd suggest every minute or every 5 minutes.

Comment: Is starting a new process at that rate so detrimental?

Answer (score 151):

Recently I have written a simple command-line utility called [`gpustat`](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat) (which is a wrapper of `nvidia-smi`) : please take a look at https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat.

[image]

Comment: It's so cool really.

Comment: I had to use ```sudo -H pip install gpustat``` comamnd to install and then i could just run ```gpustat -a -i 3``` and works like charm

Answer (score 78):

For Intel GPU's there exists the `intel-gpu-tools` from http://intellinuxgraphics.org/ project, which brings the command `intel_gpu_top` (amongst other things). It is similar to `top` and `htop`, but specifically for the Intel GPU.

```
   render busy:  18%: ███▋                                   render space: 39/131072
bitstream busy:   0%:                                     bitstream space: 0/131072
  blitter busy:  28%: █████▋                                blitter space: 28/131072

          task  percent busy
           GAM:  33%: ██████▋                 vert fetch: 0 (0/sec)
          GAFS:   3%: ▋                       prim fetch: 0 (0/sec)
            VS:   0%:                      VS invocations: 559188 (150/sec)
            SF:   0%:                      GS invocations: 0 (0/sec)
            VF:   0%:                           GS prims: 0 (0/sec)
            DS:   0%:                      CL invocations: 186396 (50/sec)
            CL:   0%:                           CL prims: 186396 (50/sec)
           SOL:   0%:                      PS invocations: 8191776208 (38576436/sec)
            GS:   0%:                      PS depth pass: 8158502721 (38487525/sec)
            HS:   0%:                      
            TE:   0%:                      
          GAFM:   0%:                      
           SVG:   0%:
```

Answer (score 48):

`nvidia-smi` does not work on some linux machines (returns N/A for many properties). You can use `nvidia-settings` instead (this is also what mat kelcey used in his python script).

```
nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q useddedicatedgpumemory
```

You can also use:

```
watch -n0.1 "nvidia-settings -q GPUUtilization -q useddedicatedgpumemory"
```

for continuous monitoring.

Comment: Glad this wasn't a comment. It's exactly what I was searching for when I came across this question.

Comment: Thanks, this is what worked for me, since I have a GeForce card which is not supported by nvidia-smi.

Comment: You can do `nvidia-settings -q all` to see what other parameters you can monitor. I'm monitoring `GPUCurrentProcessorClockFreqs` and `GPUCurrentClockFreqs`.

Comment: Thanks man, good idea to query all, since each card may have different strings to monitor!

Comment: If you just want the number and nothing else (eg. for conky) use this: `nvidia-settings -q [gpu:0]/UsedDedicatedGPUMemory -t`

Comment: for me it gives : ```Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused```

Comment: @Hossein: That might be because `nvidia-settings` looks at the X Display variable `$DISPLAY`. In a GPGPU server, that won't work - if only because such servers typically have multiple GPU's

Answer (score 48):

You can use `nvtop`, it's similar to `htop` but for NVIDIA GPUs. Link: https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop

Install on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install nvtop`

[image]

Answer (score 32):

I have a GeForce 1060 GTX video card and I found that the following command give me info about card utilization, temperature, fan speed and power consumption:

```
$ nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=power.draw,utilization.gpu,fan.speed,temperature.gpu
```

You can see list of all query options with:

```
$ nvidia-smi --help-query-gpu
```

Comment: It would be worth adding `memory.used` or (`memory.free`) as well.

Comment: thanks! For narrower info, this works too `nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=memory.used,memory.total,utilization.gpu`

Answer (score 32):

Recently, I have written a monitoring tool called [`nvitop`](https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop), the **interactive** NVIDIA-GPU process viewer.

[image: Screenshot Monitor]

It is written in pure Python and is easy to install.

Install from PyPI:

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade nvitop
```

Install the latest version from GitHub:

```bash
pip3 install git+https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop.git#egg=nvitop
```

Run as a resource monitor:

```bash
nvitop
```

`nvitop` will show the GPU status like `nvidia-smi` but with additional fancy bars and history graphs.

For the processes, it will use `psutil` to collect process information and display the `USER`, `%CPU`, `%MEM`, `TIME` and `COMMAND` fields, which is much more detailed than `nvidia-smi`. **Besides, it is responsive for user inputs in monitor mode. You can *interrupt* or *kill* your processes on the GPUs.**

`nvitop` comes with a tree-view screen and an environment screen:

[image: Tree-view]

[image: Environment]

---

In addition, `nvitop` can be integrated into other applications. For example, integrate into PyTorch training code:

```py
import os
from nvitop.core import host, CudaDevice, HostProcess, GpuProcess
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

device = CudaDevice(0)
this_process = GpuProcess(os.getpid(), device)
writer = SummaryWriter()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):

    # some training code here
    # ...

    this_process.update_gpu_status()
    writer.add_scalars(
        'monitoring',
        {
            'device/memory_used': float(device.memory_used()) / (1 << 20),  # convert bytes to MiBs
            'device/memory_percent': device.memory_percent(),
            'device/memory_utilization': device.memory_utilization(),
            'device/gpu_utilization': device.gpu_utilization(),

            'host/cpu_percent': host.cpu_percent(),
            'host/memory_percent': host.virtual_memory().percent,

            'process/cpu_percent': this_process.cpu_percent(),
            'process/memory_percent': this_process.memory_percent(),
            'process/used_gpu_memory': float(this_process.gpu_memory()) / (1 << 20),  # convert bytes to MiBs
            'process/gpu_sm_utilization': this_process.gpu_sm_utilization(),
            'process/gpu_memory_utilization': this_process.gpu_memory_utilization(),
        },
        global_step
    )
```

See https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop for more details.

**Note**: `nvitop` is dual-licensed by the **GPLv3 License** and **Apache-2.0 License**. Please feel free to use it as a dependency for your own projects. See [Copyright Notice](https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop#copyright-notice) for more details.

Comment: Works like charm with just conda virtual environment without sudo access if anyone is looking for a solution WITHOUT admin access.

Comment: For non-sudo users, `pip install nvitop` will install into `~/.local/bin` by default. Users can add `--user` option to `pip` explicitly to make a user-wise install. Then you may need to add `~/.local/bin` into your `PATH` environment variable. If there is no system Python installed, you can use [Linuxbrew](https://brew.sh) or [conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda) to install Python in your home directory.

Comment: I really like this because it shows Time-Series for both CPU & GPU. Many tools only show current usage, or Time-Series for either, but not for both. 

Answer (score 27):

For Linux, I use this HTOP like tool that I wrote myself. It monitors and gives an overview of the GPU temperature as well as the core / VRAM / PCI-E & memory bus usage. It does not monitor what's running on the GPU though.

[gmonitor](https://github.com/mountassir/gmonitor)

[image]

Comment: `nvidia-settings` requires a running X11, which is not always the case.

Comment: I reached here while searching for the same thing for AMD's APU, and found there's `radeontop` which can be installed with `sudo apt install -y radeontop`.

Answer (score 21):

For completeness, AMD has two options:

1. fglrx (closed source drivers).

   ```
    $ aticonfig --odgc --odgt
   ```
2. mesa (open source drivers), you can use [RadeonTop](https://github.com/clbr/radeontop).

   ```
    $ sudo apt-get install radeontop; radeontop
   ```

> View your GPU utilization, both for the total activity percent and individual blocks.

Comment: I'm using official [radeon proprietary driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20), but `aticonfig` command does not exists '__')

Comment: @Kokizzu 7 years a long time makes, Linux changes a lot :)

Comment: I find it dangerous for users to add this `-y`option to apt.

Many people don't understand APT and command line, they should at least have the possibility to confirm what they are doing when pasting commands from random online pages.

(also we can use apt instead of apt-get which is meant for scripts.)

Answer (score 5):

I have had processes terminate (probably killed or crashed) and continue to use resources, but were not listed in `nvidia-smi`.  Usually these processes were just taking gpu memory.

If you think you have a process using resources on a GPU and it is not being shown in `nvidia-smi`, you can try running this command to double check.  It will show you which processes are using your GPUs.

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

This works on EL7, Ubuntu or other distributions might have their nvidia devices listed under another name/location.

Answer (score 4):

Glances has a plugin which shows GPU utilization and memory usage.

[image]

http://glances.readthedocs.io/en/stable/aoa/gpu.html

Uses the nvidia-ml-py3 library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nvidia-ml-py3

Answer (score 2):

### For OS X

#### Including Mountain Lion

[iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

#### Excluding Mountain Lion

[atMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/)

> The last version of atMonitor to support GPU related features is atMonitor 2.7.1.

– and the link to 2.7.1 delivers 2.7b.

For the more recent version of the app, [atMonitor - FAQ](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/faq.html) explains:

> To make atMonitor compatible with MacOS 10.8 we have removed all GPU related features.

I experimented with 2.7b a.k.a. 2.7.1 on Mountain Lion with a MacBookPro5,2 with NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT. The app ran for a few seconds before quitting, it showed temperature but not usage:

[image: screenshot of atMonitor 2.7b on Mountain Lion]

Answer (score 2):

for nvidia on linux i use the following python script which uses an optional delay and repeat like iostat and vmstat

https://gist.github.com/matpalm/9c0c7c6a6f3681a0d39d

```
$ gpu_stat.py 1 2
{"util":{"PCIe":"0", "memory":"10", "video":"0", "graphics":"11"}, "used_mem":"161", "time": 1424839016}
{"util":{"PCIe":"0", "memory":"10", "video":"0", "graphics":"9"}, "used_mem":"161", "time":1424839018}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function appends information such as PID, user name, CPU usage, memory usage, GPU memory usage, program arguments and run time of processes that are being run on the GPU, to the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
function better-nvidia-smi () {
    nvidia-smi
    join -1 1 -2 3 \
        <(nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid,used_memory \
                     --format=csv \
          | sed "s/ //g" | sed "s/,/ /g" \
          | awk 'NR<=1 {print toupper($0)} NR>1 {print $0}' \
          | sed "/\[NotSupported\]/d" \
          | awk 'NR<=1{print $0;next}{print $0| "sort -k1"}') \
        <(ps -a -o user,pgrp,pid,pcpu,pmem,time,command \
          | awk 'NR<=1{print $0;next}{print $0| "sort -k3"}') \
        | column -t
}
```

Example output:

```
$ better-nvidia-smi
Fri Sep 29 16:52:58 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 378.13                 Driver Version: 378.13                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 730      Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 32%   49C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    872MiB /   976MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Graphics Device     Off  | 0000:06:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   35C    P8    17W / 250W |    199MiB / 11172MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1      5113    C   python                                         187MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
PID   USED_GPU_MEMORY[MIB]  USER    PGRP  %CPU  %MEM   TIME      COMMAND
9178  187MiB                tmborn  9175  129   2.6    04:32:19  ../path/to/python script.py args 42
```

Comment: Carefull, I don't think the pmem given by ps takes into account the total memory of the GPU but that of the CPU because ps is not "Nvidia GPU" aware

Comment: Wht does "off" mean in this?` 0  GeForce GT 730      Off `

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
nvidia-smi pmon -i 0
```

to monitor every process in GPU 0. including compute/graphic mode, sm usage, memory usage, encoder usage, decoder usage.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor GPU usage in real-time, you can use the nvidia-smi command with the --loop option on systems with NVIDIA GPUs. Open a terminal and run the following command:

`nvidia-smi --query-gpu=timestamp,name,utilization.gpu,utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used --format=csv --loop=1`

This command will display GPU usage information in real-time with a refresh interval of 1 second (you can change the interval by modifying the value after --loop=). The displayed information includes timestamp, GPU name, GPU utilization, memory utilization, total memory, free memory, and used memory.

Answer (score 0):

This script is more readable and is designed for easy mods and extensions.

You can replace gnome-terminal with your favorite terminal window program.

---

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--guts" ]; then
    echo; echo "    ctrl-c to gracefully close"
    f "$a"
    f "$b"
    exit 0; fi

# easy to customize here using "nvidia-smi --help-query-gpu" as a guide
a='--query-gpu=pstate,memory.used,utilization.memory,utilization.gpu,encoder.stats.sessionCount'
b='--query-gpu=encoder.stats.averageFps,encoder.stats.averageLatency,temperature.gpu,power.draw'
p=0.5    # refresh period in seconds
s=110x9  # view port as width_in_chars x line_count

c="s/^/    /; s/, +/\t/g"
t="`echo '' |tr '\n' '\t'`"
function f() { echo; nvidia-smi --format=csv "$1" |sed -r "$c" |column -t "-s$t" "-o   "; }
export c t a b; export -f f
gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --geometry=$s -- watch -t -n$p "`readlink -f \"$0\"`" --guts

#
```

License: GNU GPLv2, TranSeed Research

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it in the available answers (except maybe in a comment), so I thought I'd add that you can get a nicer refreshing `nvidia-smi` with [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch). This refreshes the screen with each update rather than scrolling constantly.

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```

for one second interval updates. Replace the `1` with whatever you want, including fractional seconds:

```
watch -n 5 nvidia-smi
watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "GPU Dashboards in Jupyter Lab"

[image]
[image]

Introduction
NVDashboard is an open-source package for the real-time visualization of NVIDIA GPU metrics in interactive Jupyter Lab environments. NVDashboard is a great way for all GPU users to monitor system resources. However, it is especially valuable for users of RAPIDS, NVIDIA’s open-source suite of GPU-accelerated data-science software libraries.[ref](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-dashboards-in-jupyter-lab/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant that lets you monitor GPU usage on a Unix command line as a continuous graph.

pip install pipeplot if you don't already have it. It's a simple curses utility.
sed -u forces it to not buffer anything, so it plots properly.

```
nvidia-smi -l 1 --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv | sed -u s/%// | sed -u s/util.*/0/ | pipeplot
```

I was nervous about installing the other apps, but this seems minimal.