# How to check GPU RAM consumption?

Tags: ram, gpu

Is there any program like `htop` which can tell me the GPU RAM consumption when I train a "Deep Learning" model?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78203/247065). It doesn't give updates like `htop` but it is a pretty decent way to monitor GPU Memory consumption.